# "Global variable" that can be accessed by others action in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm making a web version of a `WPF` program. The program is basically a robot that uses the Selenium WebDriver.

I need to use the same `ChromeDriver` instance beetwen`Actions (code below).

**The question is how can I use the same instance of `WebDriver` in others Action Functions, being available only to the user who submitted the request?**

I tried using `DI` (`.AddSingleton()`) and static class, but the instance is not unique to each user.

It's my first app using `.ASP NET`, sorry if there are any mistakes.

The following 2 routines are called via ajax after a button is clicked.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(SEIInfo model)
{
    //Routine to do login on website using SeleniumDriver()
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult StartCapturing(...)
{
    //Capture some DOM Element's texts with SeleniumDriver()
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this, it kinda makes no sense so this is likely an XY problem.

Comment: My goal is to capture information from a page and for that I am using Selenium WebDriver. Basically the ChromeDriver is initialized when Login() is called via Ajax. If the user is authenticated, they are redirected to another view. In this view there is a button that starts data capture, calling via Ajax the StartBot function of the same control.
Sorry I can't explain very well, but I need something like .AddSingleton(), but each system user with their instance of the service.

Comment: @yaagod You can save the instances in a static field of type `IDictionary<int, YourClass>`, where the key is the id of the user. This way you get the instance from the current user by his/her id.

Comment: @Progman I assume you meant to suggest `ConcurrentDictionary` to ensure it is thread-safe?

Comment: WebDriver isn't threadsafe - so you'll need to ensure you use `lock` to have only one thread talking to it at once.

Comment: Perfect, thank you all!!